# which component handle php's GET parameters in a URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting, webserver, url-parameters

In a webserver, which component handles the **translation of URL parameters to the `$_GET` global** variable?

Is that a module in PHP engine, or a module of the web server (Apache, Nginx)?

I'm asking because since I'm not using GET (only POST/ meaningfull links where parameters are already part of the link), I was searching for a way to disable `$_GET` in order to avoid someone use it accidentally.

The final goal is not to block the HTTP's GET method, but **just to disable/remove the logic that read URL's parameters and translate these into PHP's `$_GET`.**

**If possible I want to remove physically** (erasing the module file) modules that handle this. If not I want to set that option both in PHP and Webserver (in case there's some GET's logic in both packages).

Comment: "... in order to avoid someone use it accidentally." - Who is "someone"; another developer?

Comment: Yes of course. ^^ another couple developers.

Comment: We are doing a custom plugin for apache/2 and nginx for a "microserver". We are getting rid of / disabling useless stuff.

Comment: "since I'm not using GET" - I think you mean "URL parameters" (aka GET _parameters_ - which is what the `$_GET` superglobal refers to)? Can you please clarify. Or are you literally only accepting POST requests?

Comment: I'm referring to URL parameters, (otherwise we would not be able to show any static webpage ^^). We want stop translating the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

GET/POST are HTTP headers that either request/send data. These are handled by the server initially and are part of the standard HTTP request methods.

To do this in Apache, at the top of your domain config:

```
<Limit GET>
deny from all
</Limit>
```

You can test which methods are available by sending an OPTIONS request to the server. This should return all the possible methods accepted on the server end.

Edit: New answer since the question has been changed.

The PHP module in Apache can be disabled but then you can't parse PHP files. What you're looking to do is prevent the use of Query strings. The answer here is to rewrite them before they're passed on when the PHP file is parsed and run. You'll want to configure Apache to drop query strings with a rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    *.
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think there's also some logic to be disabled in PHP, the part that translates
`?name=Hannes` to `$_GET["name"]`

Comment: `<Limit GET>deny from all</Limit>` - will simply block all GET requests, ie. all regular HTTP requests! The `$_GET` PHP superglobal refers only to the query string, which is what the OP appears to be referring to. (?)

Comment: Ops in hurry mis-readed the amswer. We don't want to block GET (otherwise we would block all pages ^^). We want to get rid of the logic that translate url parameters. We don't need them, and if possible we want to get rid of modules Handling that translation (still too early to customize the webserver build, we just want to work from installation configuration, for now).

Comment: Then use a rewrite module in Apache - to remove the query strings?

Answer (score 1):

The `$_GET` PHP superglobal is set by PHP when it parses the URL's query string (request headers) made available through Apache. As far as I know you can not prevent PHP from doing this.

However, you can reset this variable at the top of your script. eg. `$_GET = Array();`

And neither can you prevent Apache from parsing the URL / query string. This is intrinsic to any webserver. Apache only parses out the query string as a whole, it does not separate it into URL parameters - that is what the server-side language parser does (PHP in this case).

The best you can do is either block requests that contain a query string or redirect to the canonical URL (since the user can always append a query string to the request).

For example, to block requests (ie. send a 403 Forbidden) that contain a query string, in your server config using mod_rewrite on Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Or, to redirect to the same URL, less the query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

On Apache 2.4 you can use the `QSD` param to Discard the Query String instead of appending a `?` to the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. ie. `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]`.

By removing the query string from the request then the PHP `$_GET` superglobal will naturally be empty.